# MATLAB Hamming Window

Tags: matlab

I have a Hamming window of length 23 having nonzero samples `N` ranging from 0 to 22.

I need to plot `w(N)` so I used

```
N=32;
L=N+1;
w= hamming(L,'periodic');
plot(w);
```

I noticed that the first sample is staring from 1 and not form 0. Is this how it should be or should I shift it by -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plot some data `y` using `plot(y)`, Matlab has to guess the `x` axis positions, so it sets the first element of `y` to be at `x=1`, the second element to be at `x=2` etc. If you want to start your plot at `x=0`, you have to specify the `x` coordinates of each element of `w`, for example by doing `plot(0:(L-1),w)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, it worked that way. Theoretically, should time domain in this application start at 0 or at 1 ? Because when I used wvtool(w) , it also started the wave from 1.